# Remove newline in text file using python

Tags: python

Code that I'm using is

```py
for fruits, u_list in d.items():
    with open(fruits, "r") as f:
        contents = f.read().strip()
    
    for id in u_list:
         contents = re.sub(id+".*","", contents)
    
    with open(fruits, "w") as f:
        f.write(contents)
```

**original - a.txt**

```
apple,2019/03/31
orange,2020/08/18
mango,2020/09/15
grapes,2017/01/08
black.plum,2018/03/13
```

**Modified - a.txt** using above code, able to remove the `mango` keyword line, However further i would like to remove space between `orange` and `grapes`.

```
apple,2019/03/31
orange,2020/08/18

grapes,2017/01/08
black.plum,2018/03/13
```

**Expected -  a.txt**

```
apple,2019/03/31
orange,2020/08/18
grapes,2017/01/08
black.plum,2018/03/13
```

Any help or suggestion would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the lines, checking if the first field is `d[file]`, and skip the line if so.

```
for file, word in d.items():
    with open(f"{file}.txt", "r") as f:
        contents = f.read().strip().splitlines()
    
    with open(f"{file}.txt", "w") as f:
        for line in contents:
            if line.split(',')[0] != word:
                f.write(line + "\n")
```

Comment: I have added my updated code in the question, please help me with new code.

Comment: If you want to remove the newline as well, use `re.sub(id+r".*\n?", "", contents)`